# Which plant's part is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany, biodiversity

[image: Part of plant]

I found this plant in Rajasthan, India.
This sample is 4-5 cm long.
This is an ornamental plant. It was a potted plant.
I put my fingertip in the photo to give an idea of size of the specimen.
I can't figure out which plant this part belongs to.
Please give the species name if you can.
I would be very thankful to anyone out there who will help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit hard to say exactly, since there is a number of possibilities. We can be pretty sure that these sample is from a [Cypress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypress), belonging to the family of [Cupressaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupressaceae), but which subfamily or species this is exactly, can't be identified here. Therefore a wider image would be necessary, but since this is a potted plant, even this might not be enough, as a lot of these plants are used in gardening.

Comment: Can u explain how one can figure out that this sample belongs to a cypress?

Comment: @Anonymous Members of the [Cupressaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupressaceae) family are the predominant group with **scale (or *scale-like*) leaves**. See [here](http://woodyplantstutorial.nres.illinois.edu/shape/sha-scale.html) & [Schulz, Knopf, and Stützel (2005)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.735.160&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Those scale-like green structures are likely to be the foliages of Platyclaudus species, they are attached densely on the branches of the plant. Hence the whole thing in your picture shall be the branch with the leaf from some kind of gynosperm tree.
It's common in Gynospermum the foliage is highly abbreviated and deformed(comparing to Angiosperm).

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It isn't clear that this adds anything to the existing answer. In addition, answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— Please take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then [edit] your answer accordingly. Thanks! 

Answer (score -1):

It is called Leyland Cypress. For more details, refer the following link. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyland_cypress